# What does this code means.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was checking out a project where this line have been used in jquery script. I don't know why this is used. Can anyone please help me why this code has been used? I can share whole function if you need.

```
$("#table_data").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();
```

Comment: It finds something in `#table_data`, and then removes what it finds?

Comment: [so] is not the correct place to learn a language basic. Read some tutorials instead.

Comment: Thanks @Some programmer dude

Answer (score 2):

Let's understand statement step by step

```
$("#table_data").find("tr:not(:first)").remove();

$("#table_data")
```

*It finds the table with id (table_data)*

```
$("#table_data").find()
```

*this will find the elements on the basis of selector* here as selector is `"tr:not(:first)"` so it will find all the `tr` except `first` one. Finally there is `.remove()` that will remove the selected rows.

*So the complete statement will remove all the rows except first one*

Comment: @SumitDatta glad that it helped you to understand how it works, you can also accept as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `#table_data`, it searches for all `tr`s that are not the first children of their container (that is, for every container, it selects all `tr`s except the first), and then removes them from the container.

Answer (score 0):

It selects all elements that do not match the given selector

[here is the official documentation](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

so what it does is, it find elements in a table that are not first in a row, and removes them.